# How can we display SKU in URL structure?

Tags: magento-1.9, sku

How can we display SKU in URL structure? e.g domain/Product name kws/industry/SKU-product type. I'm also using SKU auto generator to generate SKU's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Magento event observer  and use  catalog_product_save_before event on this function you need update magento  Product url key field (url_key)

```
<global>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <stockalert>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>yourmodel/observer</class>
                        <method>autoupdateurlKey</method>
                    </stockalert>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_before>
        </events>
    </global>
```

And Observer code is:

```
    public function autoupdateurlKey($observer)
    {
        $product=$observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $oldUrlKey=$product->getOrigData('url_key');

        $Sku=$product->getSku();
        $TypeId=$product->getTypeId();

        // put yourlogic 
        $product->getData('url_key',$YourNewUrl);

         return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Also, would it be possible to search product by changing product ID(i.e SKU). For eg. 1. http://www.ebay.in/itm/Ahilya-Cream-and-Hot-pink-Designer-Ghaghra-104-PDS-Ghaghra-/251690046301?&_trksid=p2056016.m2518.l4276.          2. http://www.ebay.in/itm/Ahilya-Cream-and-Hot-pink-Designer-Ghaghra-104-PDS-Ghaghra-/251690046401?&_trksid=p2056016.m2518.l4276.             Here just by changing the product ID from 401 to 301 took us to the product whose product id ends with 301. How can we achieve this in magento?

Comment: Any help in achieving the URL structure and functionality of ebay URL structure. Is there any API which can help in achieving the desired functionality of ebay URL structure?

Comment: i am busy now .i will reply on tomorrow

Comment: Any help on this?